# Using the Latex \multirow feature

Tags: tables, multirow

I am creating a CV using Latex and wish to display all of my qualifications in a table. A lot of the qualifications have a few of the same details, so I will require to use a lot of multirows in order to prevent repetitive text. 
Here is some example data of what I want to create:

[Example data for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YlcT.png)

I have tried to create this in Latex using the following code:

```
\usepackage[]{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \caption{Qualifications}
  \label{tab:qualifications}
  \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    Institution & Qualification Level & Course Length & Course Title 
    & Grade\\

    \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{Some College} & \multirow{3}{*}{A Level} & \multirow{3}{*}{2013 - 2015}
      & Maths & A \\
      & English & A \\
      & Spanish & A \\ \hline

    \multirow{4}{*}{Some High School} & \multirow{4}{*}{GCSE} & \multirow{3}{*}{2012 - 2014}
      & Maths & B \\
      & History & C \\
      & English & A \\
      & Spanish & B \\ \hline

    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This code works for the first line, but for the rest of the lines the last two columns end up being mixed in with other random columns.
Here is an example of what results from this code:

[Result from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE93z.png)

Does anyone know how I can achieve what I want to do? I can't find any information online about how to do this.

Thanks

**Edit: I realise I have entered different grades in the code and in the example data, but it doesn't really matter either way.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each row must describe exactly 5 columns (hence 4 ampersands `&`). If we look at your code, however, we see:

```
\multirow{3}{*}{Some College} & \multirow{3}{*}{A Level} & \multirow{3}{*}{2013 - 2015}
      & Maths & A \\ <-- OK, 5 columns
      & English & A \\ <-- not OK, only 3 columns
      & Spanish & A \\ \hline <-- not OK, only 3 columns
    \multirow{4}{*}{Some High School} & \multirow{4}{*}{GCSE} & \multirow{3}{*}{2012 - 2014}
      & Maths & B \\ <-- OK, 5 columns
      & History & C \\ <-- not OK, only 3 columns
      & English & A \\ <-- not OK, only 3 columns
      & Spanish & B \\ \hline <-- not OK, only 3 columns
```

We can fix these by adding empty column, as is shown in this working example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
Example:
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Qualifications}
    \label{tab:qualifications}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
        \toprule
        Institution & Qualification Level   & Course Length     & Course Title 
        & Grade\\
        \midrule
        \multirow{3}{*}{Some College} & \multirow{3}{*}{A Level} & \multirow{3}{*}{2013 - 2015}
            & Maths & A \\
        &&  & English & A \\
        &&  & Spanish & A \\
        \midrule 
        \multirow{4}{*}{Some High School} & \multirow{4}{*}{GCSE} & \multirow{4}{*}{2012 - 2014}
            & Maths & B \\
        &&  & History & C \\
        &&  & English & A \\
        &&  & Spanish & B \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note here that the multicolumns are centered. If you want the terms "Some Collage", "A Level" and so on to be displayed on the top row of each multi row group (as you showed in your example data), you don't need to use the `\multirow` command. Instead, just add the terms only on the first row for the rows in each "group", as can be seen in the following example:

```
% just add within document example above...
\noindent Example using just \textit{regular} rows and columns:
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Qualifications - Example 2}
    \label{tab:qualifications2}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
        \toprule
        Institution & Qualification Level   & Course Length     & Course Title 
        & Grade\\
        \midrule
        Some College & A Level & 2013 - 2015 & Maths & A \\
        &&  & English & A \\
        &&  & Spanish & A \\
        \midrule 
        Some High School & GCSE & 2012 - 2014 & Maths & B \\
        &&  & History & C \\
        &&  & English & A \\
        &&  & Spanish & B \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The resulting tables are displayed below.

[image]

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot of sense. Each website that I went on, they just wrote the code the way I wrote mine; I didn't realise you needed the extra ampersands. I'll try that method now

Comment: That's good to hear. Happy Latexing!